# D-Link DGE-530T not connecting

Tags: networking

My onboard LAN died the other day so I installed a new D-Link DGE-530T rev. C1 PCI card and disabled the onboard LAN in the bios. My computer detects the D-Link card (ethO) but will not connect to the network. If I delete the 70-persistent-net.rules file and any swap files and restart my computer it works fine. As soon as I reboot or hibernate my computer though it again will not connect. Am I missing something or does Ubuntu not support this card?  A quick response would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. P.S. I am a Ubuntu nube so a relatively detailed description of how to fix this would be great. Thanks again.